# GetFileAttributes inconsistency -- why?

Tags: c++, winapi, ntfs

Why does the following:

```
GetFileAttributes(L"D:");
```

return `0x00002010`, but the following on the exact same machine:

```
GetFileAttributes(L"\\\\?\\D:");
```

returns `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` and error code `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`?

Comment: Seems to work with "\\?\D:\".

Comment: @chris: Yes, I noticed it too.

Comment: The answer's probably in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) somewhere.

Comment: Moreover, if I do it on `"\\?\D:\"` it returns `0x00002016`, which is, it adds `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` flags.

Comment: Win32 interprets D: as the current directory on drive D, which is not necessarily the same as the root directory.  The kernel interprets \\?\D: as the D volume device; devices do not, as far as I know, have file attributes, so ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER is a reasonable result.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Can you elaborate on this one: `"Win32 interprets D: as the current directory on drive D"`?

Comment: @HarryJohnston It's a little more complex than that. A drive does not have a current directory. There is one per process. I know that cmd.exe uses private env vars to fake one per drive, but we are talking Win32 here. But if `D:` is the drive on which the process current dir lives, then `D:` refers to that current dir. Otherwise it refers to the root. Which is kind of weird!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'm about 80% sure that the "current directory" environment variables are in fact respected by at least some Win32 API calls.  (Yes, I've read the blog post you're thinking of, but I think this may be one of the rare cases where he's mistaken.)  If I can find time, I'll do some tests.

Comment: @c00000fd: if you properly specify the root directory, i.e., use D:\ and \\?\D:\, are the results still different?

Comment: I did some tests to back up what I said. I was expecting current directory not to be relevant at all actually. I was surprised to find it used when drive matched.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I've just tried, and I found that CreateFile respects the per-drive current directory, i.e., if I asked it to create c:hi.txt, hi.txt was created on the current directory on drive C, even if that wasn't the current drive.  Of course that's a different use-case than this question, but it does establish that Win32 isn't completely indifferent to the per-drive current directories.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: re "A drive does not have a current directory", that's incorrect. win32 processes do the same as cmd.exe. APPARENTLY using the very same mechanism, fake environ variables, but their existence may be just a compatibility thing.

Comment: @Cheers Not according to my tests with this API function.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you can easily list the current directories. use the `GetFullPathName` API function to get full path for each of `C:`, `D:` etc., using the drives you actually have. this way you can easily prove to yourself that you're wrong.

Comment: @Cheers The API we discuss here is GetFileAttributes

Comment: i would have directed you to my old winapi tutorial, which has (or rather had) a nice example, except that wordpress has made a mess of it, it's now unreadable. why the freaking f can't they leave things as they are. argh.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it may well be that some function(s) do not respect the current directories. however, that does not make it less wrong to say that there no per-drive current directories. it's provably wrong, and i've told you how to prove that to yourself.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So I did the test and it seems that you are in the wrong here. Win32 does not maintain multiple working directories. cmd does with env vars. And Win32 is able to pick up on those directories, but calls to `SetCurrentDirectory` don't change those env vars.

Comment: For any future readers that wonder about per-drive current directory faking by cmd.exe, you can find our more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/06/10008132.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The three examples you give in the question and comments all refer to different things.

- `\\?\D:` refers to a volume, for which file attributes do not exist.
- `\\?\D:\` is the root directory of the drive which does have attributes.
- `D:` is a little harder to define. I believe that the system uses `GetFullPathName`, or equivalent, to expand this path. So, if the process current directory is on `D`, then that directory is used. Or, if a special [per-drive working directory environment variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx) is defined for this drive, that directory is used. Otherwise `D:\`, the root directory is used.

You want to be using `D:\` or `\\?\D:\` here.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9316206 is a simple example presenting the per-drive current directories for the process, in a messagebox. if you don't have multiple drives then you can create logical drives with the `subst` command. it's a simple proof that this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Your example proves nothing. It just picks up the private environment variables from the cmd.exe process that is hosting it. If you start it from, say, explorer, with a double click on the exe, behaviour is different. I added the following to the beginning of your main function: `SetCurrentDirectory(L"E:\\temp"); SetCurrentDirectory(L"C:\\desktop");` and then ran. The output for `E` was `E:\`. It's `cmd.exe` that does all this rather than Win32.

Comment: re "Your example proves nothing", why do you persist in maintaining something doesn't exist when it has been put right before your nose? that's insane.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Try adding the `SetCurrentDirectory` calls

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, `SetCurrentDirectory` clears the per-drive current directories. that doesn't mean they're not there. you have seen that they're there wrt. `GetFullPath`. it means you can clear them. it's pretty wild to say something doesn't exist because you've found a way to remove it from sight

Comment: why is this such an uphill battle. why can't you ever concede that you're wrong no matter how strong evidence is presented.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think we'd have a better chance of meaningful conversation if you could admit that you are wrong. I'm happy to admit that I can be wrong. I've updated the answer to what I believe is accurate. Before we proceed, a simple yes/no question for you. Is it possible that you could have made a mistake?

Comment: you have seen the per-drive current directories presented in a messagebox in your face. you maintain they're not there. you have found a way to clear them. the argument is insane. why can't you ever admit to being wrong, why is that impossible for you?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The answer to the simple yes no question? No point continuing until we get that straight.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: "The amount of energy necessary to refute bullshit is an order of magnitude bigger than to produce it." :( i concede that making you admit to being wrong is impossible for me. i'm not good enough: it needs a psychologist, not an engineer. i have given you a complete program to try. i think i've done enough.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's odd that you insist that I cannot admit to being wrong. I frequently do so. You noticed my answer update. Which part of that is incorrect now? Why can't you answer my simple yes/no question? That doesn't seem very hard to do. On the evidence in this comment trail it does appear that one of us cannot admit to being wrong.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Whilst you are contemplating how to ask my difficult yes/no question you might like to see if this article helps you come to an answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/11/10073890.aspx

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Or perhaps this one (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/06/10008132.aspx) And I'll inline some quotes to entice you: *Whereas in Win32, there is only one current directory, in MS-DOS, there was one current directory for each drive*, and *Win32 does not have the concept of a separate current directory for each drive, but the command processor wanted to preserve the old MS-DOS behavior because people were accustomed to it (and batch files relied upon it)*.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Raymond for sure will admit it when he gets things wrong. A most desirable trait in a developer. Of course, it is possible for other parties to write these magic environment variables. And when a new process inherits the environment of its parent, it inherits these too. But Win32 APIs like `SetCurrentDirectory` don't set these environment variables.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I guess MSDN gets it all wrong too. It [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364934.aspx) *Each process has a single current directory that consists of two parts:
A disk designator that is either a drive letter followed by a colon, or a server name followed by a share name (\\servername\sharename)
A directory on the disk designator*

Comment: David Heffernan - exactly, thats why C:hello.txt is a valid file name/path

Comment: @paulm Exactly what, I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you're guessing in the right direction: you have seen with your own eyes that MSDN is wrong here, that `GetFullPathName` supports the per-drive current directories. which means that a path like `c:` or `c:hello.txt` can resolve differently depending on how the process was created. which means that code based on your answer here can be pretty unreliable.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf OK, it seems to me that you believe that you are right, and the rest of the world is wrong. Raymond Chen, MSDN. Both wrong. Alf. Right. I'm not going to try to persuade you to change your mind.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you have tried [the example I gave you](http://pastie.org/9316206) and you have therefore seen directly that you're wrong. you have seen the per-drive current directories, reported by `GetFullPathName`, that you maintain don't exist, yet you argued on, now with authority fallacies. that's insane. reality always trumps authority. especially such easily reproduced reality, it always trumps authority. why can't you admit to being wrong, just for once. it's not about those others possibly being wrong. it's about *your answer*, and your inability to admit any wrongness.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's more complex than that. The environment variables that Raymond describes fake the appearance of per-drive working directories. But a process has a single working directory. As stated clearly in MSDN. I can admit I was wrong. My original version of the answer was wrong. I admit that. I think I have fixed it. You don't seem able to answer my simple question. It's not very hard to answer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf What do you think the output of this program will be (http://pastebin.com/8Ebyvwsc). You might think that setting the current directory to `C:` would restore it to the directory on the `C` where we last set the current directory to. But it doesn't. It goes to whatever is in that magic environment variable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it's good that you fixed the answer. i have a good understanding of the mechanisms involved (i have blogged about them years ago). but thanks anyway for trying to teach ;-).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This one is quite interesting too: http://pastebin.com/0DaYYi6B  I've certainly learnt a lot here.

Comment: re the first, (http://pastebin.com/8Ebyvwsc), i got a little surprise when I removed the `\\windows`. as it turns out, while `SetCurrentDirectory` clears the per-drive current directories at the end, it *uses* them. a quite conflicted API function, this. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I don't think `SetCurrentDirectory` clears the per-drive directories. To use your terminology, if it *cleared* them, how could it then later *use* them? So far as I can tell (and none of this is officially documented), when you do `SetCurrentDirectory` passing `"<drive>:"` the function checks if this is the current drive. If so you get the current directory. Otherwise it looks for the special env vars, and uses the value found there. Otherwise you get the root dir.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But I've seen no evidence at all that a call to `SetCurrentDirectory` modifies these env vars.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I must comment on the way you addressed me in these comments. You were contemptuous and superior. You made it quite clear that you felt that I was beyond contempt, utterly beneath you. I don't understand why you would behave that way. Even if you feel it, you ought to conceal it.

Comment: i ran the program from drive h:, it changed to current directory on drive c:. so, it *used* that drive's current directory. but after, all per-drive current directories cleared (i don't know that that's done via the environment variables, as i said earlier it's not established that that's the only relevant state, although likely).

Comment: Although this was not immediately pertinent to my question, I appreciate you both taking time to investigate into it. As for the current-directory-per-drive argument, I believe David's assertion holds. `GetFullPathName` must be tapping into those old `=C:`-type environment variables to preserve an illusion of per-drive current directories. That is the only way to explain the results of Cheersandhth.-Alf's original example. (My guess is that the MSDN warning not to call it in the multitasking environment is the proof of it using environment variables.)